# Chart.js and Flask how to pass x/y data per dataset

Tags: python-3.x, flask, chart.js

Not working:

```
var cv = document.getElementById('lineChart')
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        
        datasets: [ 
        {
            label: "SomePlot",
            data: {x: template_labels, y: y_data},
            backgroundColor: "#33cc33",
            borderColor: "#33cc33",
            fill: false,
        },
        ]
```

Working:

```
var cv = document.getElementById('lineChart')
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: {{ template_labels }},
        datasets: [ 
        {
            label: "SomePlot",
            data: {{ y_data }},
            backgroundColor: "#33cc33",
            borderColor: "#33cc33",
            fill: false,
        },
        ]
```

1. I'd like to pass a x and y list of value for each dataset.
2. I'd like to have a scatter plot. I am able to make a scatter plot by specifying each data point (not convenient). E.g.:

   data: [
   {x: 0, y: 0},
   {x: 1, y: 10},
   {x: 2, y: 20},
   ]

I guess I have to map each x value with y?